# Is there a Pandas equivalent to each_slice to operate on dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if there is a Python or Pandas function that approximates the Ruby #each_slice method. In this example, the Ruby #each_slice method will take the array or hash and break it into groups of 100.

```
var.each_slice(100) do |batch|
  # do some work on each batch
```

I am trying to do this same operation on a Pandas dataframe. Is there a Pythonic way to accomplish the same thing?

I have checked out this answer: [Python equivalent of Ruby's each_slice(count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833589/python-equivalent-of-rubys-each-slicecount)

However, it is old and is not Pandas specific. I am checking it out but am wondering if there is a more direct method.

Comment: You could use numpy's `array_split` e.g. `np.array_split(df,100)` does this solve your problem?

Comment: Hmm. I think you'd need to do `np.array_split(df,df.shape[0]/100)` to split it into batches of ~100 in size

Comment: @EdChum that works great! You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built in method as such but you can use numpy's `array_slice`, you can pass the dataframe to this and the number of slices.

In order to get ~100 size slices you'll have to calculate this which is simply the number of rows/100:

```
import numpy as np
# df.shape returns the dimensions in a tuple, the first dimension is the number of rows
np.array_slice(df, df.shape[0]/100)
```

This returns a list of dataframes sliced as evenly as possible

Comment: how do I perform logic on each of the slices?

Comment: I got it: for x in range(len(slices))

Comment: You can just assign the output to a list and iterate over it like `slices = np.array_slice(df, df.shape[0]/100)` and then `for s in slices: dostuff`